# IT Quiz - do not show anwers unless checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make sure that at least two checkboxes are selected.  If no checkboxes are selected, then an error message appears.  This is what I have tried so far:

```
function quiz4() {
var a4 = document.getElementsByName('q4');
    for (i = 0; i < a4.length; i++) {
        if(a4[i].checked == false) {
            document.getElementById('oCorrectAnswer4').innerHTML = "Please select your answers.";
        }
    }

    if (document.getElementById('q41').checked && document.getElementById('q43').checked) {
        document.getElementById('oCorrectAnswer4').innerHTML = "Correct: The answer is " + "<u>A) Keyboard and C) Finger Print Scanner</ul>";
        inputs = document.getElementsByName('q4');
            for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if(inputs[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                    inputs[i].disabled = true;
                }//end of if
            }//end of for
    } else {
        document.getElementById('oCorrectAnswer4').innerHTML = "Incorrect: The answer is " + "<u>A) Keyboard and C) Finger Print Scanner</ul>";
        inputs = document.getElementsByName('q4');
            for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if(inputs[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                    inputs[i].disabled = true;
                }//end of if
            }//end of for
        }
}//end of q4
```

I know this does not work, as the for loop is bypassed (I guess), but I had to start somewhere.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you add the html as well or a fiddle? that would make things easier in understanding

Comment: Read this: [mcve]